# Unable to read a line from a text file

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that need to enter a directory, read a line of text in a .txt file and copy the line to another text file in a different directory and then repeat this over many different text files, each in their own specific directory.

This is what I have so far but doesn't seem to be reading the line of text.

```
for parameterfile in PB*/*.txt;
do
  parameterfile= fit_parameter.txt
  while IFS= read -r line;
  do
    echo "$line" >> full_system_parameters.txt
  done<$parameterfile
done
```

Comment: what's the purpose of this  `parameterfile= fit_parameter.txt` it's wrong (extra space after "=") and will keep setting parameterfile to the same file. There's also a typo in `done<$paramterfile` , should be `done<$parameterfile`

Comment: To collate parameters stored in separate text files into one "master file". I thought you had to set the input file as variable, am I wrong?

Comment: So to paraphrase: for each of 40 different txt files, you want to append that file content into another file? Isn't `cat PB*/*.txt >> full_system_parameters.txt` what you want?

Comment: Where would I insert this in the script Kamil? I'm new to bash and haven't use `cat` yet

Comment: You wouldn't need to insert anywhere. Just run Kamil's command :)

Comment: I need the line from each text file to be on a new line in the `full_system_parameters.txt` file. `cat` function just write continuously to the new file. @KamilCuk

Comment: And why doesn't the `cat` command work for you? What is the result? What is the expected result? The files in `PB*` folder do not contain newlines? What is their content? Can you post example files contents inside `PB*` directory structure with it's example directory structure and example output matching the input? Unless you create a fully reproducible example, It's hard to say what you mean. I don't know what you mean, can you clarify? Why is _continuous_ writing (opposed to what? calling open(3)+write(3)+close(3) for each chunk/byte/some measure of data?) anyhow relevant to the end result?

Comment: I've used  `awk 1 PB*/*.txt >> full_system_parameters.txt` and this has provided the right output I need in `full_system_parameters.txt`. @KamilCuk

Comment: nice ; ) so you want first line from all the files only. You could do the same with `head -n1 PB*/*.txt`. Post an answer to your question and accept

Answer (score 0):

I've used `awk 1 PB*/*.txt >> full_system_parameters.txt` and this has provided the right output I need in `full_system_parameters.txt`.

Comment: Why not `cat PB*/*.txt >> full_system_parameters.txt`?